# how to create custom keyboard like emoji in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, keyboard

I am creating Chat Application. I want enable emoji symbols keyboard in my project. So my question is: is it possible to do this through code?

Comment: Yes. Look at `inputView` property of `UITextField` or `UITextView`.

Answer (score 3):

you d't create emoji keyboard in ios,simply enable emoji key board in your device [( Enable emoji keyboard )](http://osxdaily.com/2011/12/19/enable-emoji-keyboard-iphone/)

```
//only user manually enable emoji keyboard in device
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply . I don't want to create emoji keyboard  ,I just want to enable that through my code for that particular textfield.

Comment: it not possible to enable emoji keyboard for particular textfield because there is no keyboard type for emoji,only user manually enable emoji keyboard in device

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a keyboard, and need to reproduce the keys in a way close to the system keyboard, I would recommend using https://github.com/acoomans/ACKeyboard

It defines ACKey that you can use as keys for your keyboard. It can save you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a UITextfield? If yes I think apple will automatically include the emoji keyboard. Try testing your app on a device and use an emoji keyboard.